# Swift NumberOfRowsInSection Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I'm trying to either show or not show my "NoPostsView" depending on my firebase database.

That's my function for finding out if there are posts:

```
func checkIfPostsExists(YES: @escaping () -> Void, NO: @escaping () -> Void)
{
     REF_POSTS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
     {
         (snapshot) in
         if snapshot.exists()
         {
             YES()
         }
         else
         {
             NO()
         }
     })
}
```

And that's how I use it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    checkIfPostsExists(YES:
    {
        if self.posts.count <= 0
        {
            return 7 // ERROR IS IN THIS LINE
        }
        else if self.posts.count != 0
        {
            self.noPostsView.isHidden = true
        }
    })
    {
        self.noPostsView.isHidden = false
    }
    return posts.count
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

I'm pretty sure it's caused due to me returning 7 in that function but I can't seem to get my head around fixing the error.

Comment: the closures are defined as `@escaping () -> Void` which means it takes no params and returns nothing. If checkIfPostsExists function does anything like going to the network or reading from a database this wont work anyway, it will always return posts.count

Comment: Thank you. But how should I do this then?

Comment: explain it fully first, what exactly does `checkIfPostsExists` do?

Comment: I have the function in my question. All it does is that it accesses the database and checks if a given child exists

Comment: I can't fully understand why you used closure to do this thing. If you want to check if something exists, then make the tableView behave based on this, you can use just reload data based on a condition

Comment: I can't explain to you why I used this but it, unfortunately, is necessary. So is there a way to do this? Really appreciate you guys helping me btw :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this...

```
// uses a completion with a boolean value to show whether has posts or not
private func hasPosts(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    // check posts and then at some point return a boolean
    completion(true) 
}

// check if has posts and either show tableView or noPostsView
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad() 

   hasPosts() { hasPosts in 
      if hasPosts {
          tableView.dataSource = self
          // maybe other logic
      }
      noResultsView.isHidden = hasPosts
      tableView.isHidden = !hasPosts
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that way I still can't return something

Comment: You *cannot* just return from an async function. async functions take time so your function returns before they finish. So you use a completion handler to 'do some work when the task has finished'. Using the example above, when you load the VC you check to see if you have posts or not and then either load the `tableView` or the `noPostsView`. The way you are doing it, `return posts.count` returns before the db has been accessed

Comment: But I'd like to still show the tableView even if there aren't any posts. Is that possible?

Comment: yes of course, just change the logic, you can review this other answer for more info on 'returning from async function': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function

Comment: Or is it may be possible to change the number of rows a tableView has outside of the `numberOfRowsInSection ` function

Comment: You said: "Just change the logic" But that is the problem I don't know how to do so

Comment: Thank you but I already use completionHandlers in my `checkIfPostsExists` function and it still doesn't work. If I'm understanding something wrong please correct me or edit your answer and show me an example. :D

Comment: I was running out of time earlier. the way i have done it in my answer is to get the data and store it in an array on the VC, so when the VC first loads, the tableview will be empty and will fetch from the db and then fill the db if there are posts. you cannot use the closure in the way you are because you are trying to fetch from the db each time it asks for the row count, which is not only inefficient and wasting resources, its also not needed. fetch the records and then use the data to fill the table. the table will fill before the user even notices anything

Comment: and your closures specify that they return nothing and you are trying to return something

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you so much!!! You've saved me a lot of time and work :D I really greatly appreciate that, thank you! c:

Comment: Your welcome :) I tried to explain that earlier but I was tight on time. Good luck with the project